# Auto-increment an value inside a column by clicking on the datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-2008-r2, auto-increment

I was wondering if there's a way you can code that with every click on the datagridview a value of one of my columns in my database auto-increments it's value by one.

I was making an c# videostore application and every time someone clicks on a movie in my datagrid the value in it's column ''clicks'' raises by one.

Comment: If I were you I would use javascript.(client side)
You can also put an event handler in the column and add the value, but you will have to do asyncpostbacks all the time.(code behind)

Comment: I'm doing it as a school project and it needs to be in c#. so yeah, that sucks.

Comment: check this, should help you [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnclick.aspx)
It also has an example at the end

Comment: Thanks a lot Ann,think this will do it! :)

Comment: Let me post the answer

Answer (score 0):

As commented:
[MSND website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnclick.aspx)

They show you how to add the event handler and then take the value you want and play with it.

Hope it helps.